# How to configure multiple apache site in Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-http-server

i would like to configure multiple web site under apache. 
I copy my website files into

```
/var/www/site1
/var/www/site2
...
/var/www/site10
```

How do i configure apache to load different site when user write:

```
http://myserver/site1
..
http://myserver/site10
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set up an Apache VirtualHost. In Ubuntu these are located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/<my site>`

Your virtual host in this case could look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName <myserver>
    DocumentRoot /var/www # Point Apache to your web directory

    <Directory />
        Options -Indexes # Don't allow Apache to show a listing of the directory if someone navigates to http://myserver/
        AllowOverride All # Allow .htaccess files in each site directory to be read
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the most simple set up that should get you up and running. Once you create this virtual host file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, run `sudo a2ensite <mysite>` to enable the site and then restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`

Navigate to http://myserver/ and you should get an access denied page, but navigate to http://myserver/site1 and you should see the correct site.